# TypeError: Expected float32, got () of type 'complex' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have some trouble with my learning code because it returns the following error when I execute it

**Error**

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tf_apprentissage/main.py", line 109, in <module>
f_de_x = model(x)  # permet de déterminer ce qu'est l'image (y = f(x) )
File "tf_apprentissage/main.py", line 91, in model
c9 = dense(c7, (-1,100, 2))
File "tf_apprentissage/main.py", line 61, in dense
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(forme, stddev=(2/n)**.5))  # poid
File "/home/etudiant/PycharmProjects/tf_apprentissage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 169, in truncated_normal
stddev_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(stddev, dtype=dtype, name="stddev")
File "/home/etudiant/PycharmProjects/tf_apprentissage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 836, in convert_to_tensor
as_ref=False)
File "/home/etudiant/PycharmProjects/tf_apprentissage/lib/python3.5/site-   packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 926, in internal_convert_to_tensor
ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
File "/home/etudiant/PycharmProjects/tf_apprentissage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
File "/home/etudiant/PycharmProjects/tf_apprentissage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 208, in constant
value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
File "/home/etudiant/PycharmProjects/tf_apprentissage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 383, in make_tensor_proto
_AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
File "/home/etudiant/PycharmProjects/tf_apprentissage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 303, in _AssertCompatible
(dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))

TypeError: Expected float32, got (8.659560562354934e-17+1.4142135623730951j) of type 'complex' instead.
```

I'm a beginner with Tensorflow so I don't where the problem is and I will be very thankful for any help.

The goal of this source code is to recognize words for a class project and first we want to recognize letters and numbers. I have never done any machine learning project before and it's the first time that I use tensorflow. we use Image of the drawn digit as input with a label.

**My code is**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import tensorflow as tf
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import os

    """
    # Model parameters
    W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
    b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
    # Model input and output
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    linear_model = W * x + b
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    # loss
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
    # optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    # training data
    x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
    # training loop
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
    for i in range(1000):
      sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})

    # evaluate training accuracy
    curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
    """
    def conv(entree, noyaux):
        n = noyaux[0]*noyaux[1]*noyaux[2]
        W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(noyaux, stddev=(2/n)**.5))  # poid aléatoire (distribution gaussienne)
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(noyaux[-1:]))  # biais
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(entree, W, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')+b
        # entree = notre image ,
        # W = poid (noyaux de notre convolution,
        # [1,1,1,1] = pas de notre convolution,
        # 'SAME' va rajouter des zeros autour de notre matrice permet une matrice de même taille
        # donc en sortie pour que le noyaux ne perde pas d'information

        return tf.nn.relu(conv)  # on applique la non linéarité


    def pool(entree):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(
            entree,
            [1, 2, 2, 1],
            [1, 2, 2, 1],
            'SAME'
        )


    def dense(entree, forme):
        n = forme[0]
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(forme, stddev=(2/n)**.5))  # poid
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(forme[0]))

        matmul = tf.matmul(entree, w)+b

        return tf.nn.relu(matmul)


    def model(entree):
        c1 = conv(entree, (3, 3, 3, 16))
        c2 = conv(c1, (3, 3, 16, 16))
        c3 = pool(c2)

        c4 = conv(c3, (3, 3, 16, 32))

        # explication du deuxième paramètre
        # 3 -> Longueur
        # 3 -> Largeur
        # 16->profondeur de la matrice 3D précédente
        # 32->profondeur de la prochaine matrice 3D

        c5 = conv(c4, (3, 3, 32, 32))
        c6 = pool(c5)

        c7 = tf.reshape(c6, (-1, 16**2 * 32))  # on ecrase notre matrice en 3d dans un vecteur
        # c6 = la matrice 3D
        # arg2 = la forme :
        #         -1 : qu'une solution
        #          16**2 * 32 = nombre d'element dans le vecteur
        c8 = dense(c7, (-1,16**2 * 32, 100))  # multiplication matricielle
        c9 = dense(c8, (-1,100, 2))
        return c9

    def resize_img(img):
        image_temp = Image.open(img)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(content = image_temp, channels = 1, dtype = tf.float32)
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image_temp,[64,64])
        return image_temp


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 64, 64, 3])  # contiendra nos images par la suite
        # tf.float32 -> type de la donnée qui serra stocké
        # argument 2 vas être la forme de x
        # None -> signifie qu'on traite plusieurs image en même temps
        # 64, 64, 3 -> résolution de l'image : 3 = profondeur

        path_to_dataset = "Hnd/Img/"
        f_de_x = model(x)  # permet de déterminer ce qu'est l'image (y = f(x) )

        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])  # les labels (ce que signifie en réalité l'image
        # fonction de cout (calcul de la distance entre ce que l'on veut et ce qu'on a
        cout = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=f_de_x, labels=y))
        step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(cout)  # on minimise notre cout (0.0001 est arbitraire)

        with tf.Session() as session:
           session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
           for dir in os.listdir(path_to_dataset):
               for file in os.listdir(path_to_dataset + dir):
                   image = resize_img(path_to_dataset+dir+"/"+file)
                   session.run(step, feed_dict={x: image, y: dir})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(forme, stddev=(2/n)**.5))  # poid
```

`forme` appears to be a complex number, on the lines above and below that you're referencing `forme[0]`, which I presume is the real part of the complex number. Whereas on the line shown above `forme` is referenced without the index to the real part of the number.

Did you want:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(forme[0], stddev=(2/n)**.5))  # poid
```

If not, print out the value of `forme` and verify that it is what you expect it to be. If you didn't mean for it to be a complex number, track down that issue.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, it still a complex and he still want float but forme is a complex, however n equal -1

Comment: You can't pass in a complex number. I don't understand why you're trying to do this?